# Memory Leak with NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndex

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak while using NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndex:
The stack frame is as follow:

```
   0 CoreFoundation __CFDataAllocate
   1 CoreFoundation __CFDataInit
   2 CoreData -[NSSQLCore _prepareResultsFromResultSet:usingFetchPlan:withMatchingRows:]
   3 CoreData -[NSSQLCore _newRowsForFetchPlan:selectedBy:withArgument:]
   4 CoreData -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:]
   5 CoreData -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:]
   6 CoreData -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:]
   7 CoreData -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]
   8 CoreData -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:]
   9 CoreData _faultBatchAtIndex
  10 CoreData -[_PFBatchFaultingArray objectAtIndex:]
  --->  11 MyApp -[DocumentViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] 
  12 UIKit -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]
  13 UIKit -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:]
  14 UIKit -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable]
  15 UIKit -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateContentSize]
  16 UIKit -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged]
  17 UIKit -[UITableView reloadData]
  18 UIKit -[UITableView layoutSubviews]
  19 QuartzCore -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
  20 QuartzCore CALayerLayoutIfNeeded
  21 QuartzCore CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
  22 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::commit()
  23 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
  24 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
  25 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoObservers
  26 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
  27 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
  28 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
  29 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal
  30 GraphicsServices GSEventRun
  31 UIKit UIApplicationMain
```

From this stack frame, it looks like the object accessed with objectAtIndex get leaked.

However, when I leave the controller, its dealloc method get called. In this method, all the objects fetched by the fetchedresultscontroller are turned into fault since I use [NSManagedObjectContext refreshObject:mergeChange].

To be complete in my description, below is the code where the leaking object is created:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Page* page = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage* thumbnail = [page getThumbnail];
    [[self managedObjectContext] refreshObject:page.image mergeChanges:NO];
    CGFloat height = [PageCell cellImageSize:thumbnail].height + 20;
    return height;
}
```

Any hint would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code where you get the `UIImage`. The leak is most likely there. Where it is exactly depends on how you create the image object.

Answer (score 1):

Barring more evidence, that looks more like a leak in the bowels of Core Data.  File a bug.

Comment: So an interesting point: if I sent the "Low Memory Warning" to the simulator, the objects disappear. Would they be some kind of caching then?